# Does android device manager remote lock if you deactivate stolen phone?

Tags: remote-control, android-device-manager, remote-access, remote-wipe

okay so my phone is stolen in airplane mode due to the security flaw on the power button....My question is if it deactivated will my android device manager lock and erase still work if the phone is connected to wifi or powered back on?

Comment: Your command of self-lock or self-wipe will be sent to device through your Gmail account. If the thief didn't change anything on phone, as soon as it has access to internet it will run your commands.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Android Device Manager will send the phone the Lock and Erase message as soon as it comes online and starts communicating with Google's servers. When the wipe occurs you will receive an email stating when and where it happened.

http://www.androidcentral.com/how-set-android-device-manager-lock-and-wipe-your-phone